# How to parse a value into a key from an outsource js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about parsing values from a different source into a key. Here is the environment:

Translation.js

```
export default {
    en: {
        translation: {
            Text: 'Text',
            Welcome:"Welcome text",
        }
    },
    tr: {
        translation: {
            Text: 'Selam',
            Welcome:"Hoşgeldiniz",
        }
    },
}
```

Now, I want to pars let say **Welcome** text into this which is a component of Ant.Design here:

https://ant.design/components/notification/

And in a different file like example.js, I have this and can react the translation.js

```
const openNotificationForNonActivated = type => {
  notification[type]({
    style:{marginTop: "42px"},
    message: 'Text',
    description: 'Welcome Text',
    duration: 5,
  });
};
```

I normally can get the translation value with this code:

```
{t("Welcome")}
```

I believe this is because I am trying to react it in a const value. So, how can I handle this?
Any idea,

Best, thanks;
Osman

Comment: what library are you using? ...next-i18next ?

Comment: this one: 
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `react >= 16.8.0`, you can create a custom hook that returns `openNotificationForNonActivated` and that so you can access the `useTranlation` hook, which will allow you to display the translated text

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { notification } from 'antd';

export const useNotification = () => {

  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const openNotificationForNonActivated = type => {
  notification[type]({
    style:{marginTop: "42px"},
    message: 'Text',
    description: t('welcome'),
    duration: 5,
  });
 };

  return { openNotificationForNonActivated };
};
```

and you can call your function in your component as follow

```
const {openNotificationForNonActivated } = useNotification();

openNotificationForNonActivated('type');
```